# Magic line navigation in Angular 2?

Tags: angular

How would I go about making a magic line navigation in Angular 2 without JQuery? My navigation items have a variable width which doesn't make it easier.

I've tried adding a list-item to my navigation for the magic line. Then I wanted to change it's width and position based upon the position and width of the active list-item. I however didn't know how to directly address the DOM (which isn't the best solution in Angular probably) to get the active nav-item's width. I tried using ElementRef, but I couldn't get it to work (even after putting it in my ngModule providers).

In plain JavaScript, this is such an easy task with little code. Is there a straight-forward Angular-way of achieving this?

Example: https://css-tricks.com/examples/MagicLine/

Comment: The question should show some effort of yours. What have you tried. Where did you fail?

Comment: Sorry, updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated Angular to the latest version and ElementRef started working.